# Is it possible to write conditional transations in redis with node js

Tags: node.js, redis

Let's say if a 'someHash' 'somefiled' exists I want to run some other redis command to change 'somefiled' to a new value, but I want these operations to be run atomicly. Is it even possible? I can't see such an option on https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis, they say that all callbacs are executed after the transation, so I don't think it is even possible... But maybe I am wrong and it is?

```
var redis = require('redis');
var mainClient = redis.createClient();
var multiCmd = mainClient.multi()

multiCmd.hexists('someHash', 'somefiled')
// Checking if exists, if so execute line below
multiCmd.hset('someHash', 'somefiled', 'newVal')

multi.exec(function (err, replies) {
console.log(replies); // 101, 2
});
```

Comment: Is that what you're looking for https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis#clientmulticommands?

Comment: You can also use [Lua scripting](https://redis.io/commands/eval) to implement whatever logic you want. node-redis supports this since "this library is a 1 to 1 mapping to Redis commands".